# What does "arch disbeliever" meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Mirza Ghulam Ahmad, founder of Ahmadiyya Muslim Community in his [lecture](https://alislam.org/library/browse/volume/Ruhani_Khazain/book/Lecture_Ludhiana/?l=English#page/2/mode/1up/selection/NzIsMTc2LDYyNywzMzA%3D) said:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain how you have tried answering the question so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Arch" means chief or principal here, as in **arch**bishop.  Go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20arch&oq=define%20arch&aqs=chrome..69i57.4809j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).  Scroll down to adjective.

Comment: Why would it not then be written as "arch-disbeliever"? Is there any other phrase where "arch" means "principal" where it would be written in two words like in the excerpt?

Comment: @Yee-Lum Likely a typo.  The charge of apostasy is deadly serious for a Muslim.  In many places, it is a capital crime.  "Playful and teasing" is completely out of place.  And as well, the Anitchrist is an arch-enemy of Jesus.

Comment: That's fair, and I see how I would be wrong upon rereading the tone of the sentence. Sounds very weird to me, though. Well, I learned something!

Comment: @Yee-Lum It's a weird language.  Three  meanings of "arch" derived from three different languages.  I think I would despair if I had to learn English as an adult.

Answer (score 0):

From dictionaries:

> arch (adj.) deliberately or affectedly playful and teasing; characteristic of those who treat others with condescension

So, a disbeliever as well as condescending toward/dismissive of those who are believers.

Comment: I doubt it.  Playful and teasing don't go along with the Antichrist.

Comment: The emphasis is "condescending", or treating 'believers' like a joke and regarding them with derision. For example, atheists often behave like this towards fundamentalists.

Comment: No, an "arch disbeliever" taken in your sense would be someone who didn't take his own disbelief seriously.